# Do i need to unmount an EBS Volume in AWS when shutting down the ECS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am using AWS since almost one year using Terraform. The resources are stopped every evening and started again in the morning. The setup looks as follows:

1. An ECS Instance is created
2. An EBS Volume is created

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume"{  
  availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
  size              = 8

  lifecycle {prevent_destroy = true}
}
```

3. The above two are connected with the terraform resource: aws_volume_attachment

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachment" {

  count = var.attach_ebs ? 1 : 0
  device_name  = var.aws_volume_attachment_device_name   
  instance_id  = data.aws_instance.ecs_instance.id   
  volume_id    = var.ebs_volume.id   
  skip_destroy = true

   lifecycle {create_before_destroy = true}
}
```

The problem:
It happens about once a month, that the ebs volume is resetted. Either to the state of the last snapshot or, if no snapshot exists, to a completely empty state. Up to now i have no clue why this happens. In 99% of the cases it works as expected, yet it doesn't work consistently.

While i'm aware about that the attachment makes sure the volume is attached and detached. I'm not sure about mounting and unmounting.
I do use a launch configuration user script to mount the ebs volume with the aws_launch_configuration.

`sudo -u root mount /dev/xvdb /mnt`

But i do not have something similar for the shutdown process and haven't found a decent answer to this.

At the moment I don't have any way to replicate this problem. It occurs without any obvious reason, still looking into it.

So, do I have to unmount the volume before shutting down the instance or does this happen implicit?

Comment: You should not need to mount or unmount at all. What are you using this volumes storage for?

Comment: i'm using the volume to persist the data of a postgres database

Comment: OK, any reason why it can't be via a managed service? Generally it is not advised to run a core database that must persist in production using containers. They should generally be ephemeral.

Comment: No there's no reason, and yes its better to use a managed service, but at the moment i can't switch to a managed service so i need to find the source of the problem.

Comment: The source of the problem is that this is the wrong architecture for hosting a database. The database should be managed outside of a container.

Comment: Nevertheless, this should work in theory since the EBS Volume is persistent.